# How do I gain access to data from the selected cell in prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, segue

I'm attempting to create my first segue and I'd like to pass data from the tableViewCell that I selected to the secondary view controller that I'm segueing to.

My question is:

**Since prepareForSegue doesn't take an indexPath, how do I gain information about the particular cell that I selected?**

here's a photo of my app with some dummy data in it, the cells with arrows to the right represent the cells that I want to segue from:

[image]

This is my CustomCell class that those rows are derived from:

**TimingCell.swift**

```
class TimingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var timingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSetLabel: UILabel!

    ...
}
```

here is where I am setting up my segue method:

**ViewController.Swift**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SettingCellDelegate {


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    var view: TimeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController


}
```

***please let me know if you need to see anymore code in the comments below**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should be segueing from the UITableViewController, not just the view controller.

Inside the UITableViewController, you need to have a  an override for:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return 6 //Looks like you have six rows in your TableView
}
```

Now you need a class-scope NSIndexPath variable to keep track of the index of the row that was selected, so to create the variable:

```
var path = NSIndexPath()
```

Now you need two more overrides, the first to set the path variable when a row is selected, the second to deselect the row after you select it (ensures the deselect animation doesn't play when you transition back to the tableview from the child view controller):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    path = indexPath
    return indexPath
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(path, animated: true)
}
```

Finally, in your prepareForSegue function, you may use the path variable to determine which row was selected and set the child view controller variables accordingly:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var dest = segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController
    if path == 1 {
        //set some destination variables here
    } else {
        //or here
    }
}
```

And if you have a data structure from which you're determining what each row in the table view will contain, just use path as an index to the data structure and pass that row's information to the destination view controller. For example, something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var dest = segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController
    dest.rowTitle = myRowsArray[path.row].title
}
```

Table views are a bit to get used to... good luck!

Comment: I just tested this, this works well... I've upvoted and will select an answer tomorrow. thanks again James

Answer (score 1):

You can get `IndexPath` this way:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


   var view = segue.destinationViewController as! TimeViewController
   if let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            view.tempString = indexPath.row.description
        }

}
```

Comment: my unwrap is failing, your reference to myTableView... I switched it with tableView, I'm not sure what else to switch it to

Comment: no error it was just not firing the inner code, I'll try this again today

Answer (score 1):

You can set some variables in your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` function. Set the same variables in the view you're trying to get to. Set the values in the `prepareForSegue` function, and it will work.

The following are the codes I use for my application. I set the roomUUID in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function, and pass it in the `prepareForSegue` function. There is a roomUUID variable in the destination segue view controller too.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println ("Select Row At: \(indexPath.item)")
    // Need to show the view for room information.
    var roomInfo: NSMutableDictionary = self.roomList[indexPath.item] as NSMutableDictionary
    self.roomUUID = roomInfo["uuid"] as String
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowRoomInfo", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let roomInfoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RoomInfoViewController {
            if let identifier = segue.identifier{
                if identifier == "ShowRoomInfo"{
                    roomInfoViewController.roomUUID = self.roomUUID
                    println ("Show Room Info")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: hi yuting, I'll take a look at your answer sometime throughout the day, thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

In the `prepare(for segue:)` method, use this:

```
guard let indexPathOfSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
    fatalError("Unable to determine which cell is selected")
}
```

Then you can get the index like this:

```
indexPathOfSelectedRow.row
```